# Is there anyway to click a text input and have a dropdown with HTML in it appear?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm trying to figure out how to create a clickable text input field that once clicked, displays a dropdown that is HTML, not a select box (similar to a bootstrap mega menu https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-mega-menu)

I'm not entirely sure how the HTML should look but I'm imagining something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />

<div class="searchDropDown">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
             <!--some elements here....-->
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The closest thing I can find that might do this is select2 but I'm very beginner with Jquery plugins and it looks fairly complicated especially for what I'm looking to do.

Can anyone recommend anything? Been searching around for ages and not coming up with very much

Comment: did u try show and hide?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
<label for="myBrowser">Choose a browser from this list:</label> 
<input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" /> 
<datalist id="browsers"> 
   <option value="Chrome"> 
   <option value="Firefox"> 
   <option value="Internet Explorer"> 
   <option value="Opera">
   <option value="Safari">
   <option value="Microsoft Edge">
 </datalist>
```

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: I tried this but I need to add divs and images within and this won't let me unfortunately